# Can't install Apns on my debian GCE instance

Tags: python, linux, django, apple-push-notifications

I have a GCE instance with Debian wheezy on it, I'm running my phython/Django code (my beckend) for an IOS application.

I'm trying to use a [TSL push notification library](https://github.com/djacobs/PyAPNs) but I'm failing to install it

- sudo easy_install apns -
  got an error: Setup script exited with error: file '/tmp/easy_install-sOkSjl/apns-2.0/apns-send' does not exist
- sudo pip install apns -
  got an Exception & error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
- sudo pip install pyapns -
  didn't work either

if I copy it to my GCE instance how do I install & configure it, in Github documentation only states how to use easy_install.

Answer (score 2):

When I was trying to install apns using pip, I also got the "apns-send does not exist" message. This was solved by [downloading this script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/djacobs/PyAPNs/master/apns-send) from their git repo and placing it in the build folder (in my case, build/apns).

For some reason, it seems it is not included in the version on PyPI.

Comment: did you copy the folder to your server? if yes when you pip install do you supply the entire path to the folder?

Comment: I did it via SSH to my Vagrant server (virtual). When executing sudo pip install apns, it created a build folder for me before crashing (/vagrant/build). I just downloaded apns-send, placed it inside /vagrant/build/apns/ and then reran sudo pip install apns from the same path I executed the command first (in my case, /vagrant/).